# Change UITableViewCell's background color in iOS 14

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios14

In my iOS app, I want to change the appearance of the selected `UITableViewCell`. Here's what I have and it works perfectly, except that on iOS 14 I get an error messaging saying that `selectedBackgroundView` is `nil`. What do I need to change here so it works on iOS 14 as well?

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    self.selectedBackgroundView!.backgroundColor = selected ? UIColor.grey : .white
    menuLabel.textColor = selected ? UIColor.darkGrey : UIColor.primaryDark
    iconImageView.tintColor = selected ? UIColor.darkGrey : UIColor.primaryDark
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
self.contentView.backgroundColor = selected ? UIColor.grey : .white
```